# A relation between area and diameter of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Let $|T|$ and $h_T$ the area and the longest side of a triangle $T$, respectively.

Is there a constant $C$ (independent of the triangle) such that $|T|\leq C h_T$ ?

Comment: Diameter of a triangle? Strange!

Comment: I was using the usual definition of diameter of a set, which in a triangle match with its longest side value. I edited the question to clarify that. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: $|T|/h_T=h$ where $h/2$ is an altitude of the triangle. You can find a sequence of triangle $T_n$ such $h_n\to \infty $, so the inequality is impossible. But we have $|T|\leq 1/2 h_T^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a bit of [dimensional analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) will show you that you're trying to establish an inequality between an area, which is length squared, and a length. This will never work. Take any triangle where your equation is satisfied (for some assumed $C$). Double all its edge lengths, and you have a triangle with twice the edge lengths but four times the area. Repeat that process, and sooner or later the inequality has to be violated.

There can only be an generally true inequality if the units on both sides agree. So you need the power of two lengths, a squared length, or use the square root of the area on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the maximum side is $h_T$, the altitude to this side has a maximum length of $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}2 h_T$. Hence, the following inequality is true
$$T \leq \dfrac{\sqrt3}4 h_T^2$$